# fill chart from csv file

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, visualization

I have csv file with data:

```
1,1671790171,75
0,1671790182,11
1,1671790193,11
0,1671790212,19
1,1671790239,27
0,1671790248,97
1,1671790342,94
0,1671790361,19
1,1671790368,79
0,1671790408,40
1,1671790417,90
0,1671790432,15
```

I need create application to show chart where first data is "work" or "not work", second data is linuxtimestamp data and time, third data is the number of seconds the process took.

I wrote something like this:

```
    // Use OpenFileDialog to allow the user to select a CSV file
    var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
    {
        Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv"
    };

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Clear the chart
        chart1.Series.Clear();

        // Read the CSV file
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog.FileName))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');

                // Parse the values
                var working = values[0] == "1";
                var timestamp = long.Parse(values[1]);
                var duration = int.Parse(values[2]);

                // Convert the Unix timestamp to a DateTime
                var date = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(timestamp).UtcDateTime;

                // Create a new series in the chart
                var series = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series
                {
                    Name = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
                    Color = working ? Color.Red : Color.Green,
                    BorderColor = Color.Black,
                    ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar,
                    IsXValueIndexed = false,
                    XValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.DateTime
                };
                series.Points.AddXY(date, duration);
                chart1.Series.Add(series);
            }
        }

        // Set the bar width for all series
        foreach (var series in chart1.Series)
        {
            foreach (var point in series.Points)
            {
                // point.Width = 20;
                point.BorderWidth = 0;
            }
        }
```

However, I need help with replacing so that on line X there are all occurrences (i.e. each line) with preferably a vertical entry of the date of occurrence, and on line Y there is time of operation (i.e. the last data from each line)

Comment: C# isn’t a visual framework and therefor has no chart. What User Interface are you talking about WinForms, WPF, Blazor, MAUI or ….

Comment: I use WinForms.